# How to write time delay transfere function in Scilab?

Tags: scilab

How can I write a time delaly transfere function like TF=(e^-10*s/(s+1)) in Scilab by using syslin('c', num,den) command or any other command. I know there is a continuous fix delay block in Xcos, but I would like to write this transfere function in Scinote file.

Answer (score 1):

The iodelay toolbox is available for Scilab:
https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/iodelay

Comment: Should I install this toolbox to Scilab 6.1.1 or this for the previous versions. Is there any command or another way to do this in the latest version?

Comment: The latest iodelay toolbox | 0.4.8 can be installed directly for any Scilab 6.1.x version, including the 6.1.1 one.